# Why Docker container with --link and restart policy isn't started?

Tags: docker

I have two containers, the first one is redis and the second one is my app which has --link to redis container. They both have [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart):

```
docker run --restart=on-failure:10 --name redis redis 
docker run --restart=on-failure:10 --name app --link redis app
```

Then when I `sudo service docker stop` and then `sudo service docker start` only redis container is started. BTW, if there isn't --link in the app container it's started as well.

My Docker version is 1.7.1.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already try to use `--restart:always` instead?

I assume that your `app` container is not restarted because it ended successfully during `docker stop`. `redis` might be restarted due to an error (did you have a look at `docker logs` for the `redis`container?). So when you specify `--restart:on-failure:10` in that situation it would work as designed because only `redis`was failing.

Comment: Then why my app container is started if I remove `--link redis`? I think if there is an error the behavior wouldn't be dependent on `--link`..

Comment: Finally, yes, the problem was in containers. If I use `--restart=always` then after `sudo service docker stop` and then `sudo service docker start` the containers are started OK. But I'm using vagrant and after `vagrant halt` and then `vagrant up` some containers are stopped that's because of vagrant mounts shared folders after the docker service is started. So,  containers which use volumes linked to vagrant shared folder cannot start because there aren't any files at the moment.